# Replacing Multiple lines of text within a text document with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have text file with multiple lines of two different phrases.  I want to change each one of those phrases sequentially sequentially (<<Not redundant).  This is to say, for example, take a text file with the following:

```
Test  <>
some seemingly random stuff
Results <>
more seemingly random stuff
Test  <>
Gibberish
Results <>
more gibberish
Test  <>
lines of stuff here too
Results <>
more lines of stuff here as well
Test  <>
a few more pages of garble
Results <>
Even more garble at the end of what I am concerned with.
```

What I want to do with such a file is to input data between the <> for each line, but it would contain a sequential numerical indicator.  I want to change it to look like this:

```
Test <This is for test 1:>
some seemingly random stuff
Results <Values for test 1:>
more seemingly random stuff
Test <This is for test 2:>
Gibberish
Results <Values for test 2:>
more gibberish
Test <This is for test 3:>
lines of stuff here too
Results <Values for test 3:>
more lines of stuff here as well
Test <This is for test 4:>
a few more pages of garble
Results <Values for test 4:>
Even more garble at the end of what I am concerned with.
```

What I have tried is:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\test-directory\Test-Text.txt | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace "Test <>", "Test <This is for test >" `
       -replace "Results <>", "Results <Values for test >"
    } | Set-Content c:\test-directory\New-Test-Text.txt
```

Now... THIS works VERY WELL...almost.  What I need to implement; and I am just not seeing how, is some way of telling it to put 1 after the first line, 1 after the second line, 2 after the third line, 2 after the fourth line, 3 after the fifth line... etc.
I was thinking about trying to use:

```
$_ -replace "Test <>", "Test <This is for Test $N" `
   -replace "Results <>", "Results <Values for test $N>"
```

and have some way of forcing $N to increase ($N = $N+1) at every output... but I have no idea how to do that.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For some reason...what I view on screen is missing some of what I typed.  If I hit "edit" it shows up, but when I hit cancel... it does not.  so... to ensure this makes sense:  What I have tried is as such:  Get-Content -Path C:\test-directory\Test-Text.txt | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Test <>", "Test <This is for test > " ` -replace "Results <>", "Results <This is for test >" } | Set-Content c:\test-directory\New-Test-Text.txt

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily using `switch`:

```
$n = 1  # set the starting number
$newContent = switch -Regex -File 'C:\test-directory\Test-Text.txt' {
    '^\s*Test\s+<>'    { 'Test <This is for test {0}:>'-f $n }
    '^\s*Results\s+<>' { 'Results <Values for test {0}:>'-f $n++ }
    default         { $_ }  # return this line unchanged
}
$newContent | Set-Content 'C:\test-directory\New-Test-Text.txt'
```

---

Alternative for very large files, you can write the output within the switch, so it is not collecting everything in a variable first and then write to disk.
Of course, this will make the whole thing work slower because of more disk write actions..

```
$n       = 1                                        # set the starting number
$outFile = 'C:\test-directory\New-Test-Text.txt'
'' | Set-Content -Path $outFile                     # create or empty the resulting file

switch -Regex -File 'C:\test-directory\Test-Text.txt' {
    '^\s*Test\s+<>'    { Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value ('Test <This is for test {0}:>'-f $n) }
    '^\s*Results\s+<>' { Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value ('Results <Values for test {0}:>'-f $n++) }
    default         { Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value $_ }  # write this line unchanged
}
```

Output:

```
Test <This is for test 1:>
some seemingly random stuff
Results <Values for test 1:>
more seemingly random stuff
Test <This is for test 2:>
Gibberish
Results <Values for test 2:>
more gibberish
Test <This is for test 3:>
lines of stuff here too
Results <Values for test 3:>
more lines of stuff here as well
Test <This is for test 4:>
a few more pages of garble
Results <Values for test 4:>
Even more garble at the end of what I am concerned with.
```

Comment: This does not seem to function.  I've spent some time pouring over it without success.  I have a couple of questions about this: 1)  You have two lines that I assume would be identical, but they are not:  '^Test\s+<>'    { 'Test <This is for test {0}:>'-f $n }
    '^Results\s+<>' { 'Results <Values for test {0}:>'-f $n++ }  If I remove the ++ from the results line, or add them to the Test line, I still get no count on the output file.  The other question I have 2)  What is the first part of those lines?  ( 'Results\s+<>')  Is that pointing the script to the position in file?

Comment: @NoBody Using your own example this works (see output). The `$n++` increments at the `Results.,` line, which is what you asked for.

Comment: If I take out the part that I asked about, the 'Results\s+<>' part... then it sort of works.  It will put the numerical values in (but only on the results lines) and it deletes all of the in-between stuff.  That's not desirable.  Additionally, If I add a Test line and duplicate the results line, then it will alternate the test line statement and the results line statement--but it adds 1 to each iteration (not 1,1 - 2,2 - 3,3  // but rather 1,2 - 3,4, - 5,6).  Additionally, it still removes all of the in-between stuff.  Neither of these two characteristics is desirable.

Comment: Ok... I don't know what I was doing wrong, but I went back and copied an pasted again and it worked.  Thank you.  Now I just have to make it work on the real project, which is significantly larger.  Thank you!

Comment: OK I found out why I had a preliminary failure in my testing.  It seems that those values (both) are precluded with some tabs (or other type of hard-coded spacing).  IF I delete that spacing, it works.  If I don't... no go.  Then again, If I delete that spacing, then whether or not I re-add it, the form will not work.  Is there a way to tell it to look only for that data and ignore any spaces around it?

Comment: @NoBody Please see my edits. I have changed the regexes, so now it can handle zero or more whitespace characters in front of each line (space, tab, return etc.) I have also added an alternative for if your file should be too large to fit into memory.